# Drawing canvas on button

Tags: android, button

I have xml like this

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
    `android:orientation="vertical"`
    `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`
    `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`
    `android:background="#dde1ec"`
    `>`
    `<Button` 
        `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
        `android:id="@+id/button_manage_expenses"`
         `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` 
         `android:background="@drawable/ic_manage_expenses"`
    `></Button>`
  `</LinearLayout>`
And Code

```
Button buttonManageExpenses = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button_manage_expenses);           
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        Paint paint = new Paint(); 
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL); 
        canvas.drawPaint(paint); 

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
        paint.setTextSize(20); 
        canvas.drawText("Some Text", 10, 25, paint); 
        buttonManageExpenses.draw(canvas);
```

I want to draw a canvas on button, Am i doing in correct way?? Please correct me

Comment: why would you want to do this? There might be a better way to achieve what you are trying to, if you could explain the reason.

Comment: Actually i want to show a badge on button, that is i want draw a circle on button, and put some numbers on that circle. Is there is any better way to do this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the canvas to drawable and set the button's background to the drawable:

```
Button b;
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(int width, int height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
// Do stuff in canvas here
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
b.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It will change the background image, I want keep the current background image and  put the canvas over the background image, Any idea??

Comment: You could try overriding the onPaint() function of the button and creating the canvas in there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for directly. But you can set a button to have an icon. If you're doing it in XML, add the line `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/circle_icon` (replace the word "Left" with whatever side you want the image to be on. You can choose from "Top", "Bottom", "Left", "Right"). If you want to set a button's image in code, use this line `button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.circle_icon, 0, 0, 0);`. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, using `button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.circle_icon, 0, 0, 0);` we can display only static image, if i want a badge numbered 100, in this case i have to save 100 images

Comment: Hmm... I understand what you mean. I'm not too sure how you might do that then. I'll let you know if I come across anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to create a composite widget, which has a Button and an Imageview, position them properly in the xml, and then, you will have better control over everything. You could do it your way as well, but it's going to be a lot of code.

Say, design a CustomButton extending LinearLayout, add a Button and ImageView to it, which of course, overlap in some sense. Now, from your CustomButton class, you can expose methods which would directly interact with your button and imageview.